# Estimating absolute difference between two conditions

Tags: distributions, meta-analysis, group-differences, clinical-trials

A clinical trial examines the effect of two treatments upon lung function.  Patients in each group contribute data at baseline and at the end of the trial.  Baseline data are provided for each group and then end of treatment data.

[image: Data]

I need to calculate the mean change (SD) over the time of the trial for each drug so that I can use the data in a meta-analysis - how should I approach this?

Comment: The mean change can be found by subtracting the final mean from the baseline. But if this table you show is all the information you have, then you cannot calculate the standard deviation for the changes from baseline just from that. Have a look at [this page](http://handbook.cochrane.org/chapter_16/16_1_3_2_imputing_standard_deviations_for_changes_from_baseline.htm), it explains possible ways to impute the missing standard deviations for changes from baseline.

Comment: Thank you I had seen this a while ago and couldn't for the life of me find it today.  It's the "[correlation coefficient] might be hypothesized based on reasoned argument" bit that's getting me!